# How to get what we says to Siri in our app

Tags: ios, swift5, sirikit, sirishortcuts, nsuseractivity

Is it possible to get what we says to Siri to get in a label in my app?

**I get the intent or activity type , but what I need is if we say "Hey Siri, show me my account balance" then I "show me my account balance" must printed on a label in my app.**

I shall be thankful for your support.